# docker-compose file for nodejs, mongo, redis, rabbitmq

Tags: mongodb, docker, redis, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I need a docker compose that have node 12, mongo 4.4, redis 4.0.6 and rabbitmq 3.8.9 . This is what I have in my docker-compose right now and apparently it does not work. The app can't seems to connect to redis and rabbitmq.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: malllog-main
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    external_links:
      - mongo
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
  mongo:
    container_name: malllog-mongo
    image: mongo:4.4
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  redis:
    container_name: malllog-redis
    image: redis:4.0.6
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: malllog-rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.9
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
      - '5672:5672'
```

Comment: how are you trying to connect to these services from your application?

Comment: You shouldn't need any kind of "link" in present-day Docker.  Does deleting the `external_links:` section help?  (The `container_name:` are also unnecessary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the docker-compose file that I have used for my microservice test project, which works for me as you can try this out.

```
       version: '3'
       services:
         my-ui:
           container_name: my-ui
           build: ./my-ui
           ports:
             - "80:80"
           depends_on:
             - my-api
           networks:
             - test-network

         my-api:
           container_name: my-api
           restart: always
           build:
             context: my-api
             dockerfile: Dockerfile
           ports:
             - "8080:8080"
           #command: mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=docker
           depends_on:
             - rabbitmq
             - mp-redis
           networks:
             - test-network

         rabbitmq:
           container_name: rabbitmq
           image: rabbitmq:management
           ports:
             - "5672:5672"
             - "15672:15672"
           restart: always
           networks:
             - test-network

         mp-redis:
           container_name: mp-redis
           image: redis:5
           ports:
             - "6379:6379"
           restart: always
           networks:
             - test-network

         mp-mongodb:
           container_name: mp-mongodb
           image: mongo:3.6
           restart: always
           environment:
             MONGO_DATA_DIR: /data/db
             MONGO_LOG_DIR: /dev/null
           volumes:
             - mongo-data:/data/db
           ports:
             - "27017:27017"
           command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
           networks:
             - test-network

       volumes:
         mongo-data:
       networks:
         test-network:
```

Comment: How is this different from the `docker-compose.yml` in the question?  What specific action should the questioner take?

Comment: @DavidMaze As Questioner didn't mention the exact error so it's not possible to provide solution for that specific question hence I helped with complete compose file so he can refer it as our both project docker file seem to be similar but what I consider that there might some image version issue in his docker file or there is highly possibility that no network has been created or attached to each service.